# how to inject jms, database properties to application server in auto deployment process?

Tags: maven, application-server, cargo, maven-cargo

We have created weblogic/jboss deployment structure from maven package goal using profiles . But we are facing problem to set propeties for jms(queues , topic) ,database properties to set in application server config files 
We uses ANT task which read propeties from properti file and inject them in xml files of application server but this is complex task and also not easy to maintain

```
 i)what is standard way to inject propeties to server before starting it?
 ii)Can and How we do this using maven-cargo plugin?
```